# How to download video from the tweet URL?

Tags: python, twitter

I listen to tweets and get media in the `https://t.co/` format. How can I download the video from this link using Python?

I tried `wget` but in this case, it downloads html page

Comment: do you have direct link to the video

Comment: @NikolayTsvetanov "https://t.co/"  + "ILkOg1Xsct". Do you mean that link?

Comment: [see this repo](https://github.com/inteoryx/twitter-video-dl)